# Is there anyway to use Instagram to edit and save photos locally but not share?

Tags: instagram

I like using Instragram to enrich and edit photos but I do not want to share them. Is there anyway to do that? I have googled and people have suggested turning off Wi-Fi or go to airplane mode but that seems really annoying to have to do each time.

Is there any way in Instagram to just use locally?

Comment: Which OS/app are you using?

Comment: You would probably be better off using a camera application that has "Instagram-like" filters.

Answer (score -2):

Well one of the way is to just capture the photo and apply the filter but never post it.

Comment: That’s exactly what the OP is asking for; can you elaborate on how to do it?